# Popular datatable jsf

Tags: java, jsf

Pessoal sou iniciante em JSF, gostaria de uma dica, como posso popular uma datatable através de uma seleção de um combobox que traz uma lista de itens do banco.

Comment: Você esta usando JSF ou Primefaces?

Answer (score 0):

Se estiver utilizando o JSF 2.0 ou superior, você pode usar o componente `f:ajax`

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.itemSelecionado}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.itens}" var="item" itemLabel="#{item.nome}" itemValue="#{item.id}"/>
    <f:ajax listener="#{bean.listarDataTable}" render="idDoDataTable"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```